# How to make this kind of illustrations for manual/guides?

Tags: illustration

I am going to write some guides and I'd like to start to make some beautiful illustrations/pictures.

This kind of pictures are often seen in product manuals I think. How can I make my own?

Is there any software which can do this? Or online web tools...

Thanks a lot!

Here is the [example picture](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/BU3r3eo6OCTtnw2Gl7y5Mw?feat=directlink).

Comment: the example picture seems to have gone.

Comment: Closing this as it's a very broad question and the only specific detail (the linked image) is no longer valid.  If you edit your question and flag it, it may be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking, that's called 'technical illustration'. More specifically, that's an 'exploded view'.

'How' you do that is a rather huge question. Typically, it involves going to school for architecture, mechanical drafting, technical illustration, industrial design or the like. It's a skill that isn't just picked up from a tutorial.

As for software, you could use a wide variety of tools to varying degrees...CAD (AutoCad, SketchUp, Turbocad), illustration (Inkscape, Adobe Illustrator, Photoshop, etc.), or good ol' paper, pencil, markers and maybe a drafting table.

Comment: Good keyword:) I am googling "technical illustration" and find lots of stuff now... Thanks!

Comment: SolidWorks does great exploded views.  Of course, that's assuming a hefty budget of both time and money...